# Laser based localization in a map without movement

Tags: ros, localization, navigation, laser, position

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am looking for an implementation of a localization algorithm that calculates the best fitting robot position based on a laser scan and a know map. The navigation stack expects odometry measurements and do not support an initial estimation without any movements?

Best wishes from Germany

Enjoy the weekend

Poseidonius

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37059/laser-based-localization-in-a-map-without-movement/) by [Poseidonius](https://answers.ros.org/users/248/poseidonius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 427 on 2012-06-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-06-22**:
Are you attempting to publish an odometry message or are you trying to provide the initial estimation?

**Comment by [Poseidonius](https://answers.ros.org/users/248/poseidonius/) on 2012-06-22**:
I want to provide an initial position estimation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In fuerte, you can check out the FLIRTlib stack: http://kforge.ros.org/projects/startuploc/services/git/ .  It's not released yet, but the code and launch files are documented.

---

Originally posted by [bhaskara](https://answers.ros.org/users/95/bhaskara/) with karma: 1479 on 2012-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2